# checkin using fbgraph in facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am bit confused in using checkin api. Every time when I call `"me/checkins"` the response i get is empty. I have no idea how actually checkin works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe to view checkin's of a user, your application will have to request for "user_checkins" access from the user. This is probably why it is coming back empty. 
Just add "user_checkins" as another permission you will need granted.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

Comment: I have added "user_checkins","friends_checkins" and "public_checkins" all these three premission . Even though I am same empty result

Comment: Try forcing a re-authentication with FB on your iOS app.  If you change the app's requested permissions, but don't re-auth, FB won't update your app's permissions.  I made this mistake, re-auth fixed the issue.